# Elasticsearch-rails, highlights query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

I'm trying to get highlights from the Elasticsearch-rails gem, but I can't get it to work.

My search method:

```
query = {
  query: {
    filtered: {
      query: {
        match: {
          _all: params[:q]
        }
      },
      filter: {
        term: {
          active: true
        }
      }
    },
  },
  highlight: {
    fields: {
      _all: {fragment_size: 150, number_of_fragments: 3}
    }
  }
}

@results = Elasticsearch::Model.search(query, [Market, Component]).results
```

When I map my results in the view to check if there are any highlights, I get an array of `false`:

```
= @results.map(&:highlight?)
```

I read through the Elasticsearch docs here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html and the gem's documentation here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model and my query seems to be correct. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: `_all` in elasticsearch represent actual field `_all` that contains combination of all your fields. So if you have `name` and `descrption` all will include `name`+`description`  ...it's good for debugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the solution was to use `"*"` instead of `"_all"`:

```
query = {
  query: {
    filtered: {
      query: {
        match: {
          _all: params[:q]
        }
      },
      filter: {
        term: {
          active: true
        }
      }
    },
  },
  highlight: {
    tags_schema: "styled",
    fields: {
      :"*" => {}
    }
  }
}
```